# Why tests with Minio fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, minio

I develop with NestJS and my server uses `Minio` to store files. For some reason, when I do E2E tests with jest - most of the times only one test that include `Minio` upload succeeds, while the other tests that include Minio upload fail due to timeout (the default timeout which is `5000 ms`). I know I can increase the timeout but I think I will just face it again later on when I will have more tests. It seems like for some reason the `MinioClient` object becomes slower when there are multiple upload requests.

Is there a better way to solve it than increasing the timeout?

Thanks in advance.